# Access indexed tokens in Solr filter class

Tags: solr, filter, lucene, indexing, token

I would like access the indexed tokens in a custom Solr filter class. The class is a regular filter from the `schema.xml` with the `<filter />` tag. Is this possible?

A little background: When a query comes in I would like to replace some of the query tokens with other tokens, but only if they are in the index for this field. Imagine for example that I would replace a query token with all the tokens from the index that start with the query token, sort of like a wildcard search. When querying for "text:te" the actual query might be "text:test | text:tent | text:temple", if "test", "tent" and "temple" are in the index for the field "text".

I have looked around the API (`TokenFilter`, `TokenStream`, `AttributeSource`) but could not find any way to access the index. I couldn't even find information about which field is currently being processed, but I see how conceptually this might not make sense.

So, is there a way to access the index? What I would need in the end I guess is an instance of `org.apache.lucene.index.Terms`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is what a [`PrefixQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/PhraseQuery.html) already does (and [`MultiTermQuery`s](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/MultiTermQuery.html) in general), via the `rewrite` method.  Is there some reason that is not adequate.

Is there some reason you don't want to use Lucene's provided queries, like `PrefixQuery` or `WildcardQuery`?

Comment: I use [EDismax](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_4_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/search/ExtendedDismaxQParser.html). In order to get a `PrefixQuery` I would have to formulate my search query like `test*`, right? I would like to spare my users from having to do this manually, depending on the context the prefix search should happen automatically.

Comment: I don't believe there exists any edismax functionality that automatically performs prefixquery, depending on context.  I'd recommend adding the `*` to the end of the user's query, when appropriate, in your implementation.